# GPE/GWT Plugin Doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

My eclipse 4.2 Juno can’t install anything related to Google App Engine Java SDK & Google Web Toolkit. I have seen similar questions & answers. They suggested opening eclipse with –clean argument, running with administrative permissions, installing plugins with administrative permissions etc. I tried all of them & needless to say none of them worked. Whenever I check for “**what is already installed**” I can see them installed but they don’t appear anywhere.
[image: Plugins Are Greyed]

I am using Android SDK bundle which is Eclipse Juno wrapped with android tools. As long as these plugins/SDK s have compatibility issue with android plugins it shouldn't matter.

Installed plugins/SDKs looks like [image: This One]

or [image: This one]

Comment: Is staying with indigo an option? ^^

Comment: Do you permit untrusted code? If i install something from google it always tells me that the source isn't trusted.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question's Title? Indicate that GPE plugin is not visible/accessible when installed on Junl's Android SDK bundle. Your current question is just too generic!!!!!

Comment: Actually GPE,GWT, google app engine java sdk none of them are working. That's why I asked such a generic question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried installing all the above plugins with JUNO. It works. The order of installation for me is -

Juno Java EE -

```
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1
```

GPE - GWT and GAE

```
Online - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2
Offline - https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip
```

Android -

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Comment: My android tools work right
I installed Android SDK Bundle,SO android tools are installed by default.

Comment: Do u use JDK 6? I am thinking my JDK 7 can be a issue

Comment: Try installing the way we have done. Juno EE, GPE and then Android. I have Juno launching with JDK 7 as default.

Comment: No sure. But we use EE as GWT means a web project and it supports EE related validations when required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who is more stupid Google Engineers or me. But the point is they failed to mention one simple thing, Eclipse EE is must, Eclipse Classic won't work. In the end my problem is solved & I am happy now :D.

But one curious question remains. What grey icons refer to? If they refer to something good, like things are working or something like that, I urge the developers to choose a different color. The way things are now Its simply weird

Comment: Well it might be just eclipse's issue. Also, you can upvote or select the answer and close the question. :) Cheers.